# How do i retrieve a localized Linkedin signin page

Tags: java, linkedin-api

I am trying to integrate linkedin sign in api with my application . However there will be candidates who will not speak english . So how do i make request that will present me with a localized sign in api ?
My current request is something like this which redirects me to sign in page 
[https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?client_id={myclientId}&response_type=code&privacyPolicy=false&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8443%2Fplayer%2Fshloauth2%2Flinkedin&scope=r_liteprofile+r_emailaddress](https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?client_id=%7BmyclientId%7D&response_type=code&privacyPolicy=false&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8443%2Fplayer%2Fshloauth2%2Flinkedin&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is overwhelmed, you can use [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) in the middle. It has a already done connection for LinkedIn and on the other side it has a lot of connectors to Java, JS etc. 
[Metalog](https://metalop.com/2015/06/11/multilingual-support-and-adding-custom-locales-in-keycloak-1-2-0/) provides a short description how to do localization.